# Route two modules to the same URL in Flask by session

Tags: python, routes, flask, werkzeug

I have a not-logged-in module/blueprint, `welcome`, and a logged-in blueprint, `home`. I want a user with a valid session to go to `home.index`, and a user that is a guest to go to `welcome.index`. However, I am running into issues because both of those functions route to the same URL, `/`.

How can I make this functionality possible? I have tried adding:

```
if(logged_in():
    redirect(url_for('home.index'))
```

to `index()` in the welcome blueprint, but this of course just causes a circular redirect, because the URL for `home.index` is the same as `welcome.index`.

I have also tried to only define `welcome.index` if `logged_in()` is true. However, that causes issues because there are other links on the site that link to `welcome.index`, and if the user is logged in, those cause errors as `welcome.index` technically no longer exists.

### Edit

I am seeing this error `AttributeError: 'Blueprint' object has no attribute 'index'` from this code:

```
from flask import Flask, session, g

from modules.welcome import welcome
from modules.home import home as home

from modules.home import index
from modules.welcome import index

 app = Flask(__name__)
 app.config.from_pyfile('config.cfg')

 app.register_blueprint(welcome)
 app.register_blueprint(home)

 @app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
 def index():
    if 'user_id' in session:
        return home.index()
    else:
        return welcome.index()
```

### Edit #2: Blueprints code

Code in modules/home.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, session, g

from models.User import User
from helpers.login import *

home = Blueprint('home', __name__)

def index():
    return render_template('home/index.html')
```

Code in modules/welcome.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, redirect, url_for, request, session, g
import md5

from models.User import User
from helpers.login import *

welcome = Blueprint('welcome', __name__)

def index():
    alert, email = None, None
    if request.method == 'POST' and not logged_in():
        email = request.form['email'] 
        password_salt = md5.new(request.form['password']).hexdigest()
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email , password_salt=password_salt).first()
        if user is None:
            alert = "Wrong username or password!"
        else:
            session['user_id'] = user.id
            return redirect(url_for('home.index'))
    return render_template('welcome/index.html', alert=alert, email=email)

@welcome.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('welcome/about.html')

@welcome.route('/tandp')
def tandp():
    return render_template('welcome/tandp.html')

@welcome.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('user_id', None)
    return redirect(url_for('welcome.index'))

@welcome.route('/register')
def register():
    error = None
    return "HI"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Split up your methods, test for logged status and then call the proper function (adding the params you need on each):

```
from ????? import app
from ????? import logged_in
import home.index
import welcome.index

@app.route('/')
def your_basic_index_view():
   if logged_in():
       return home.index()
   else:
       return welcome.index()
```

Or do the same with a decorator. You won't be able to use a single route pointing conditionally to two different views.

**EDIT:**

Try the following:

```
from flask import Flask, session, g

from modules.welcome import welcome
from modules.home import home as home

from modules.home import index as h_index
from modules.welcome import index as w_index

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('config.cfg')

app.register_blueprint(welcome)
app.register_blueprint(home)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if 'user_id' in session:
        return h_index()
    else:
        return w_index()
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able (I think) to import the function using `from modules.home import index`, etc. Now though, I'm getting `'Blueprint' object has no attribute 'index'`, even though I have an index function defined in both blueprints.

Comment: Declare these functions as bare functions - do not decorate them with the `route` decorator.

Comment: I did make them bare functions, I tried restarting the app too and it seems to be giving me the same error.

Comment: I suspect your blueprints have lots of other methods and routes

Comment: Yes, they do. I'm not sure how that would connect to the error but I have updated my answer with the full code of each blueprint file. I have not written any other methods other than `index()` yet for `home` because I just started writing the app.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try your latest edit- perfect, that did the trick! Thank you very much for helping me out.

Comment: There were two imports, one importing welcome and another one importing index (twice). What I did was specifically extract the intended function from the module, and skip any modul reference (as these where pointing to the blueprint, and as they were not being registered there, they were not available)